# returning the address of a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to return the address of a pointer using the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x = 5;
    int *p = &x;
    //int **pp = &p;
    cout << &p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However what gets printed is 0x28fea8, which is the same address as x itself. Now if I uncomment the only commented line above and leave everything else as is, then what gets printed is 0x28fea4 which seems to be the correct address of the pointer.

My question is why do I need the uncommented line in order to display the correct address of my pointer?

Why do "cout << p << endl" and "cout << &p << endl" both display 0x28fea8 if that line is left commented?

Shouldn't "cout << &p << endl" display 0x28fea4 regardless of the other line?

I'm using Qt Creator as my compiler/ide if that helps. I downloaded my compiler from the following link: http://web.stanford.edu/~rawatson/qt/windows_install/index.html

EDIT: Ok how silly of me. My issue was that I was comparing addresses by changing values and then re-running the program. Instead I should have compared by printing them all in one program run. When I compare in one program I get different addresses for p and &p, as it should be.

Comment: Can you add the used compiler flags to your post? Your example works fine on G++ 4.8.4 on Ubuntu with -O3: I get two different outputs when I print p and when I print &p.

Comment: `However what gets printed ... is the same address as x itself.` [False.](http://rextester.com/RZRVU60305) `p` and `&x` are the same. `&p` is different, as the nature intended.

Comment: maybe it's my compiler, I updated my post with a link to where I downloaded it from.

Comment: The program you show only prints one value, not two, so it's not clear what you are comparing to what else. Show the exact code you are running, and the output the program produces, which includes both values.

Comment: ya just figured out my issue was that I compared addresses from different program runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce what you are telling, with [this](http://ideone.com/EhFYkk) code:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    int* p = &x;

    printf("x address: %p\n", &x);
    printf("p value: %p\n", p);
    printf("p address: %p\n", &p);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
x address: 0xbfd6bba8
p value: 0xbfd6bba8
p address: 0xbfd6bbac
```

which is correct and indeed `&p` is `&x+4` which is correct on a 32bit architecture since they are allocated on stack.

Comment: ya my issue lied in the fact that I compared addresses from different runs of my program. To get a proper comparison, I should have printed the addresses in one program run like you did.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 5;
int *p = &x; // b stores addres of variabile a

cout << "Adress of x is : " << p <<endl; // printing the  adress of a
cout << "Value of x is : " << *p << endl; // printing the variabile stores in a 

int **pp = &p; // pp stores thea adress of p
cout <<"Adress of p is" << pp << endl; //printing the adress of p
cout << "Adress of x is" <<*pp << endl; //printing the adress of x
return 0;
```

I hope that the comments solve your problem .